# Searching on multiple columns in linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to linq. I am trying to write a linq query that will search on 3 fields in a database. However if any of the fields a blank or nothing then it will not include that field in the query.

The search object

```
Public Class Search
    Public Property firstName As String
    Public Property surname As String
    Public Property address As String
End Class
```

The Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user] (
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[firstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[surname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[fullAddress] [nvarchar](1050) NULL
```

My attempt but this will not get any data back

```
(From it In db.user 
 Where (
     searchItems.firstName IsNot Nothing 
     AndAlso it.firstName.Contains(searchItems.firstName)) 
 AndAlso (searchItems.surname IsNot Nothing 
     AndAlso it.surname.Contains(searchItems.surname)) 
 AndAlso (searchItems.address IsNot Nothing 
     AndAlso it.fullAddress.Contains(searchItems.address)) 
 Select it).
 ToList
```

Also I need to limit this to 250 records

Thanks in advance 
Paul

Comment: _"how limit this to 250 records"_, use `Take 250`. Are you sure that you don't want to use `OrElse` instead of `AndAlso` in the outer `Where` conditions (the brackets suggest)?

Answer (score 0):

Each of your string checks should additionally check that the value is not an empty string ("").  If you add an additional check to each of your string checks, you should be able to accomplish this, Eg:

```
(From it In db.user 
 Where (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItems.firstName)) Or (it.firstName.Contains(searchItems.firstName))
 AndAlso (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItems.surname) Or (it.surname.Contains(searchItems.surname)) 
 AndAlso (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchItems.address) Or (it.fullAddress.Contains(searchItems.address)) 
 Select it).Take(250).ToList
```